# I have to retun an array, not a linked list

Tags: python, arrays, reference

Reference Diagram: [image: diagram]

I have to return the array. So far I have written my code. But I am not sure if the return array matched with the diagram.

```
def return_shape():
    list_1 = [(0, 2), None]
    list_2 = [(1, 2), None]
    list_3 = [(2, 2), None]
    list_4 = [(3, 2), None]
    
    list_5 = [(0, 1), list_1]
    list_6 = [(1, 1), list_2]
    list_7 = [(2, 1), list_3]
    list_8 = [(3, 1), list_4]
    
    list_9 =  [(0, 0), list_5]
    list_10 = [(1, 0), list_6]
    list_11 = [(2, 0), list_7]
    list_12 = [(3, 0), list_8]
    
    list_13 = [None, list_12]
    list_14 = [list_11, list_13]
    list_15 = [list_10, list_14]
    main_list = [list_9, list_15]
    
    return main_list
```

Comment: Not gonna lie, this looks like a very scuffed implementation of linked lists...(Why would you use lists to implement lists?)

Comment: The main_list, as well as list 14 and 15 look backwards to me.

Comment: It isn't clear what structure you want your array to have. The diagram is of a linked list of linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange question. My first intuition would be to return a linked list.

Anyway, shouldn't you be returning `[list_15, list_9]`instead of `[list_9, list_15]` based on the order?

Tip: it would be better if you sticked to the same numbering convention. (e.g. left to write, increment from list 1 to list 4)